# annotate gem rails configuration give error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, annotate

Ruby: 2.3.0p0

Rails version : 4.2.6

annotate gem version: 2.7.1

On doing `rails g annotate:install` gives me this error:

```
(erb):34:in `template': uninitialized constant AnnotateModels (NameError)
from /Users/newput/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `eval'
from /Users/newput/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `result'
from /Users/newput/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:116:in `block in template'
from /Users/newput/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:53:in `render'
from /Users/newput/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in invoke!'
from /Users/newput/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:62:in `open'
from /Users/newput/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:62:in `block in invoke!'
from /Users/newput/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:116:in `invoke_with_conflict_check'
from /Users/newput/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:60:in `invoke!'
from /Users/newput/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:94:in `action'
from /Users/newput/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:25:in `create_file'
from /Users/newput/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:115:in `template'
from /Users/newput/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/annotate-2.7.1/lib/generators/annotate/install_generator.rb:9:in `copy_tasks'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solves your error, but I got same error by following steps:

```
  $ rails new hi
  $ cd hi
  $ echo "gem 'annotate', '2.7.1', require: false" >> Gemfile
  $ bundle
  $ rails g annotate:install
  Running via Spring preloader in process 29328
        create  lib/tasks/auto_annotate_models.rake
  (erb):34:in `template': uninitialized constant AnnotateModels (NameError)
          from /home/hibariya/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `eval'
          from /home/hibariya/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `result'
          from /home/hibariya/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:116:in `block in template'
  ...
```

I think this error can be fixed by requiring the annotate-gem in advance.
So when I removed `require: false` from `gem 'annotate', '2.7.1', require: false` in the Gemfile then the error was fixed.

Comment: Hmm. Have you placed `gem 'annotate'` under any group in the Gemfile? If the group and the RAILS_ENV don't match, the gem won't be loaded and same error will be occurred.

Comment: Thanks, moving `annotate` into development bundle works.